# Snowflake to S3 unloading (parquet format), Epoch timestamp is getting unloaded as negative value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

I am trying to unload snowflake table to S3 in parquet-format, but the EPOCH timestamp is getting as negative value. The select query at snowflake side gives the correct epoch value, but the unloaded parquet file (viewed under parquet-viewer) has a negative value.
**snowflake value = "1665136431585000" & parquet value = "-914239720"** .Can someone point the missing piece ~thankx

```
alter session set ENABLE_UNLOAD_PHYSICAL_TYPE_OPTIMIZATION = false; 

copy into@PUBLIC.STAGE_mystage/ABC/abc.parquet from ( 
  (date_part(EPOCH_MICROSECONDS ,transactiontimestamp)) :: INT as transactiontimestamp
from mydb.public.mytable
 
)
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET COMPRESSION = None) 
header = true
overwrite = true
SINGLE = TRUE ;
```

Comment: Can you try casting it to Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

casting it to snowflake-bigint worked

Comment: I'd recommend accepting your answer since it solved your issue